# How to not apply a plugin for a specific task?

Tags: gradle

I have a simple `build.gradle` script like this:

```
apply from "$rootDir/aws.gradle"
apply from "$rootDir/common.gradle"

tasks.register("deployOnAws") {
 ...
}

tasks.register("deployOnMyPc") {
 ...
}
```

What I want to do is that when I launch the task `deployOnMyPc`, it should not include this line : `apply from "$rootDir/aws.gradle"`

But I don't figure out how to achive this ?

Comment: You're not applying any plugin, so what's the question??

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pass a flag / project property which can be condition for `apply from aws.gradle`
because any condition evaluation should happen before the whole gradle is initialised

ex: `gradle -PawsDeploy=true deployOnAws`

with in the main build.gradle

`if (project.hasProperty('awsDeploy')) apply from "$rootDir/aws.gradle"`